# Missing price fields in Magento Bundle products

Tags: javascript, magento

I am getting the following JS error on bundled product pricing could anyone help me to the reason why this could be please. It looks like a conflict or a result of the missing fields. It appears this is causing the pricing to display incorrectly

```
TypeError: $(...) is null

$('price_type').observe('change', changePriceTypeMap);
```

[image]

This is what is supposed to appear like
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will help you, but I recently had a similar issue with certain attributes not appearing in bundle and grouped products. It turned out that when we upgraded Magento 1.5 to 1.9, certain attributes did not apply to the new product types. I.e. if you check your price attribute under catalog->attributes->manage attributes, check to see if bundle products are selected under the 'apply to' section. Then do the same for any other missing attributes.

Kam